# Create parent child structure from array of objects and list of dimension in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, grouping, javascript-objects

I got sales data from mysql table group by state,city and product.
I used bellow query to get the data from MySql table

```
select state,city,product,sales from salesTable group by state,city,product;
```

And got bellow output from query,

```
[
  {
    "state": "S1",
    "city": "CITY1",
    "product": "P1",
    "sales": 1000
  },
  {
    "state": "S1",
    "city": "CITY2",
    "product": "P1",
    "sales": 2000
  },
  {
    "state": "S1",
    "city": "CITY1",
    "product": "P2",
    "sales": 2000
  },
  {
    "state": "S2",
    "city": "CITY1",
    "product": "P1",
    "sales": 1000
  },
  {
    "state": "S2",
    "city": "CITY2",
    "product": "P1",
    "sales": 2000
  },
  {
    "state": "S2",
    "city": "CITY2",
    "product": "P2",
    "sales": 2000
  },
  {
    "state": "S3",
    "city": "CITY1",
    "product": "P2",
    "sales": 1000
  },
  {
    "state": "S3",
    "city": "CITY2",
    "product": "P2",
    "sales": 2000
  }
]
```

Now I want to create parent child structure from `dimensions=["state","city","product"]`
where state is grand parent, city is parent(child of state) and product is child.

**Where dimensions array should be dynamic, it might increase or decrease in length.**

I need bellow output,

```
[
  {
    "sales": 5000,
    "state": "S1",
    "children": [
      {
        "sales": 3000,
        "state": "S1",
        "city": "CITY1",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 1000,
            "state": "S1",
            "city": "CITY1",
            "product": "P1"
          },
          {
            "sales": 2000,
            "state": "S1",
            "city": "CITY1",
            "product": "P2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sales": 2000,
        "state": "S1",
        "city": "CITY2",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 2000,
            "state": "S1",
            "city": "CITY2",
            "children": [
              {
                "sales": 2000,
                "state": "S1",
                "city": "CITY2",
                "product": "P1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sales": 5000,
    "state": "S2",
    "children": [
      {
        "sales": 1000,
        "state": "S2",
        "city": "CITY1",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 1000,
            "state": "S2",
            "city": "CITY1",
            "product": "P1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sales": 4000,
        "state": "S2",
        "city": "CITY2",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 4000,
            "state": "S2",
            "city": "CITY2",
            "children": [
              {
                "sales": 2000,
                "state": "S2",
                "city": "CITY2",
                "product": "P1"
              },
              {
                "sales": 2000,
                "state": "S2",
                "city": "CITY2",
                "product": "P2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sales": 3000,
    "state": "S3",
    "children": [
      {
        "sales": 1000,
        "state": "S3",
        "city": "CITY1",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 1000,
            "state": "S3",
            "city": "CITY1",
            "product": "P2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sales": 2000,
        "state": "S3",
        "city": "CITY2",
        "children": [
          {
            "sales": 2000,
            "state": "S3",
            "city": "CITY2",
            "children": [
              {
                "sales": 2000,
                "state": "S3",
                "city": "CITY2",
                "product": "P2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this. On the first iteration, we build the tree with temporal objects instead of arrays for easier distribution. On the second recursive iteration, we make arrays from temporal objects and calculate sales.

For unification, the topmost level also uses `.children` key and its `.sales` overall sum. This can be ignored by using `result.children` instead of `result` at the end.

```js
const data = [
  { state: 'S1', city: 'CITY1', product: 'P1', sales: 1000 },
  { state: 'S1', city: 'CITY2', product: 'P1', sales: 2000 },
  { state: 'S1', city: 'CITY1', product: 'P2', sales: 2000 },
  { state: 'S2', city: 'CITY1', product: 'P1', sales: 1000 },
  { state: 'S2', city: 'CITY2', product: 'P1', sales: 2000 },
  { state: 'S2', city: 'CITY2', product: 'P2', sales: 2000 },
  { state: 'S3', city: 'CITY1', product: 'P2', sales: 1000 },
  { state: 'S3', city: 'CITY2', product: 'P2', sales: 2000 },
];

const dimensions = ['state', 'city', 'product'];
const childKey = dimensions[dimensions.length - 1];

const result = { children: Object.create(null) };

for (const entry of data) {
  let parrent = null;
  let current = result.children;

  for (const dimension of dimensions) {
    let slot = current[entry[dimension]];
    if (!slot) {
      slot = current[entry[dimension]] = Object.create(null);
      slot.sales = dimension === childKey ? entry.sales : 0;

      if (parrent) {
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(parrent)) {
          if (k !== 'children' && k !== 'sales') slot[k] = v;
        }
      }

      slot[dimension] = entry[dimension];

      if (dimension !== childKey) {
        slot.children = Object.create(null);
      }
    }

    parrent = slot;
    current = slot.children;
  }
}

normalizeAndSum(result, null);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, '  '));

function normalizeAndSum(object, parent) {
  if (object.children) {
    object.children = Object.values(object.children);
    for (const child of object.children) normalizeAndSum(child, object);
  }
  if (parent) {
    parent.sales = parent.children.reduce((acc, { sales }) => acc + sales, 0);
  }
}
```